# Set up LDAP server on arch Linux - database cannot be opened

Tags: ldap, openldap, archlinux

I tried to install an LDAP server on arch linux. I followed the procedure from the arch linux wiki : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenLDAP.

At the point `slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/`, it fails with the error :

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
58130d8d mdb_db_open: database "dc=example,dc=com" cannot be opened: No such file or directory (2). Restore from backup!
58130d8d backend_startup_one (type=mdb, suffix="dc=example,dc=com"): bi_db_open failed! (2)
slap_startup failed (test would succeed using the -u switch)
```

On the website there stands `if you do not have a database yet, you might need to create one by starting and stopping the slapd.service using systemd )`  but how do I do this? And dose this solve the error?

How can I get this right?

Comment: Is it importad where I run it? It gave me the error: Oct 28 15:37:51 myhostname slapd[7774]: slapd stopped.
Oct 28 15:37:51 myhostname slapd[7774]: connections_destroy: nothing to destroy.
Oct 28 15:37:51 myhostname systemd[1]: slapd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 28 15:37:51 myhostname systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenLDAP server daemon

Comment: Yes, after editing slapd.conf you have to start slapd at least once for the configuration to take effect. I deleted my previous comment because it was misleading, "starting and stopping the slapd.service using systemd" actually means running `systemctl start slapd` and `systemctl stop slapd`.

Comment: Just restart the procedure from the beginning and follow it carefully, if it fails to start again at this point it might be due to a misconfiguration, in this case I would check ldap logs before going further. Once `slaptest -f` run successfully you will be able to make updates on the fly but note that this part is specific to OpenLDAP version 2.4 and above. Check your openldap version.

Comment: @EricLavault the slaptest says: mdb_monitor_db_open: monitoring disabled; configure monitor database to enable

Answer (score 0):

just in case bois, if you have issues with service restart or any issues with access, restart the database creation process with ldap and own the directories to ldap user
Example :-

```
sudo chown -R ldap:ldap /etc/openldap/slap.d
```